# Calling PHP methods on XML Tag

Tags: php, xml, methods, tags

i want to call a specific PHP method when i get a specific XML Tag.
Something like thisthat
And the PHP goes $this->makeTextarea($text);
How can i achieve this?
I know it would work with call_user_function() with the tag names but it is a dirty solution.

Anybody an idea/hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the tag name in a variable like `$tag` and the function you want to call has the same name, you can call it simply by:

```
$tag();
```

Comment: That was pretty simple. Thanks a lot.